# DNSimple SSL for Ruby on Rails Heroku App - Which Email to Use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, dnsimple

I've got a Ruby on Rails app setup with Heroku and DNSimple, however when I went to purchase an SSL certificate for the site it shows the following:

```
Send Email to Approve SSL Certificate

Select an active email address from the list below. You will receive an email to approve the SSL    certificate.


Approver *
yvyvdhnrrl@whoisprivacyprotect.com
admin@______.org
administrator@_______.org
hostmaster@______.org
postmaster@_______.org
webmaster@______.org
admin@www.______.org
administrator@www.______.org
hostmaster@www.______.org
postmaster@www.______.org
webmaster@www.______.org
```

(I removed the actual site's name for privacy reasons)

How am I supposed to claim one of these email addresses and use it to finish the approval process of my domain's certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ssl-certificates-email-approval/

> The email approval is required for domain-validated certificates.

You need to use an email you have access to. It is required to approve the certificate, you will receive an email from the CA.

Comment: If my domain's email is protected by WHOIS, and DNSimple uses the publicly available information for the registrant when deciding which emails may be used to verify an SSL, how do I get the confirmation email sent to myself? (Since all of my contacts are hidden with the WHOIS service)

Comment: We do not use your contact information for certificate approval. The CA uses administrative contacts and the contact visible in the whois. As explained in the link I posted, you need to temporary disable the WHOIS privacy if you want to use the email in the whois.

Comment: I guess I need to do some more learning, because I still don't understand how to setup email to be received at one of the "@_____.org" addresses for purposes of receiving the SSL Certificate confirmation email (I know it must be done somehow through my Ruby on Rails App and/or Heroku?)

Comment: It has nothing to do with Heroku or Rails. You need to configure an email in your email provider for the domain. If you don't have one, you can use a temporary email forwarder http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/email-forwarding/